# vue.js barcode scanner produces a "keypress" event only when the user is on an input box. What event to listen to when user is not on an input box?

Tags: vuejs2

I work with a manual barcode scanner

I want the possibility of capturing the scan event without a input box, except that wherever I am and scan the code I can listen to it and do the required action.

I tried using the following code in the mounted and created functions but did not print the console.log:

```
window.addEventListener ('keypress', function (e) {
   console.log ('window scanner barcode');
})

document.addEventListener ('keypress', function (e) {
  console.log ('document scanner barcode');
})
```

Thank you

Comment: I add setInterval and its work

Comment: Hi s.br, what do you mean you added setInterval? I'm running into the same issue - I've got a webapp with vue.js that listens to keycode shortcuts outside of the context of an input element. It works when using the keyboard, but not the scanner.

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching and experimenting. A few things to consider:

- Scanners simply forward on keyboard events. Some scanners do keydown instead of keypress. Either experiment or contact technical support for your scanner
- The keyboard event does indeed get fired whether an input is focused or not
- My scanner (and I would assume most scanners), will enter each character that is scanned one character at a time. Therefore a string like '123' that is scanned would trigger 3 keypresses: '1', '2', '3'.

Based on this, it's up to you to create the proper logic in your javascript to handle the scanner input.